# Регулярные выражения java - начало(конец) строки либо пробел

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение.

> (ourRegex)

Каким образом задать так, чтобы:

1.Либо строка начиналась с него, либо перед ним пробел.
2.Либо строка им заканчивается, либо после него пробел.

Регулярное выражение вида:

> (\s|^)(ourRegex)
>   (\s|$)

жестко привязывает к началу и концу строки

Comment: `lookahead` и `lookbehind`?

Comment: Извиняюсь, не указал метку Java

Comment: Я далёк от Java, но поверхностный поиск в инете, говорит мне, что он вроде бы поддерживает просмотр вперёд и назад. Попробуйте... Для примера, возьмём такой вариант: `(?<=\s|^)([0-9]+)(?=\s|$)`

Comment: P.S. Сейчас проверил сам и, по крайней мере в песочнице, [отработало нормально](https://ideone.com/jcdJJp). На сам код прошу внимания не обращать, т.к. я первый раз в жизни сталкиваюсь с Java ))

Comment: @Deonis всё действительно работает. Спецы регулярок Java посоветовали использовать подход "подтвердить отсутствие знака, отличного от искомого" нежели "подтвердить наличие искомого знака", но ваш совет тоже рабочий. Благодарю )

Comment: рад, что хоть чем-то помог ))

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо использовать

```
(?<!\S)Шаблон(?!\S)
(?<!\S)(?:Шаблон1|Шаблон2...)(?!\S)
```

где

- `(?<!\S)` - пробел или начало строки
- `(?!\S)` - пробел или конец строки.

Во втором случае `(?:...)` является незахватывающей подмаской, которая используется для группирования нескольких выражений.

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/N1Y2n2/1).